# Wireshark Timestamp is getting changed to current time after coverting hex value to pcap file with text2pcap command

Tags: python, linux, wireshark

I have reading the pcap file frame by frame , if the frame conatain with mulitple FDM message I am spliting the data base on users in frame. while in this process getting the below error.
a.  Timestamp – After the modification of frame, the time is taken has current time , i have not made any changes related to timestamp
b.  Fragment error-Observed that after splitting , the frame bytes is getting reduced in output file.
Before:
[image: frame before conversion]

After:
[image: frame after conversion]

Requesting to suggest some solutions to handle this issue.

[Input pcap file with timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnKHW.png)

[output file after Conversion and timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg1ho.png)

[This is an example of a frame with haveing multiple users and FDM message and original time stamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMESf.png)

[After splitting the packet with individual data for the respective user getting fragment error(BIP reassembly issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoILq.png)

Comment: It isn't at all clear to me what it is that you've done, how you've split the data and what your expectations are.  Screenshots of pcap files aren't particularly helpful.  Maybe provide a sample pcap file somewhere and describe the exact steps you're currently taking to try to split this data.

Comment: I have an Input pcap file with the FDM message and Multiple users , Input pcap file will be in huge data, So the python script using (tsahrk Command) "tshark -r 5GBipL2L1_filtering_off.pcap -Y "frame.number >= 1 && frame.number <= 50000" -w out_1to50000.pcap"  By this command, it will split the huge input file into smaller files.  These smaller files will be go frame by frame by converting the frames to JSON format with the command "tshark -T jsonraw -r 5GBipL2L1_filtering_off.pcap -V frame.number == 1"  by this JSON rawdata the script will split the data based on length.

Comment: Well first, why not just use [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) to split the large file into multiple files, each of up to 50000 packets?  For example: `editcap -c 50000 -F pcap 5GBipL2L1_filtering_off.pcap out.pcap`.

Comment: Second, frame numbers will be numbered 1-50000 in each output file, so frame 109 will only be the same as the original file's frame 109.  Basically, all files' frame 109 will actually be frame N*50000 + 109 of the original file, for each output file where N is a value of 0 to (M-1), and where M is the maximum number of output files.  In any case, this means that frame 109 in all but the first file could have a completely different packet size than the original file's frame 109 because it'll be a completely different packet.

Comment: Third, you don't show any timestamps and you haven't provided any details about the version of Wireshark/tshark that you're using, so I can't really comment on the timestamp issue.

Comment: I have attached the frame snap details above, you can see the difference in the time stamp.

Comment: And what do the timestamps look like if you split the file using `editcap`, as I suggested?

Comment: yes it's the same, but while doing text2pcap to generate the output pcap file the timestamp is taking as the current time(in this case of the first packet the current system time is used, while subsequent packets are written with timestamps one microsecond later than that of the previous packet.). (eg: 0000    02 40 43 80 12 16 02 40 43 80 11 12 81 00 20 c9 89 51 21 52 00 38 17 00 01 16 00 02 04 06 00 00 00 00 17 01 52 01 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 4f c3 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 0a 02 7d 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff)

Comment: Nowhere previously did you mention anything about using `text2pcap`.  You are leaving out details that are very likely the root cause of your problem.  Please *exactly* describe what you're doing, especially how you're generating the hex bytes in the first place.

Comment: Ok let me explain the overall view, for example I have huge pcap file as a input .I am firstly splitting that input pcap into smaller pcap files. Next with the smaller pcap file I am converting the frames to json formate , with this json data i will get the raw data of the frame ,based on the requirement i am splitting the frame if it contains FDM message and multipl user , with use of hex bytes , like this i am writing to text file  as shown in previous comment this i will check for each frame ,atlate all the data will be return text file with that text file using text2pcap command.

Comment: With help of text2pcap generating the final pcap file

Comment: OK, well [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html) **can** read timestamps if they are present in the file preceding the hex bytes by using the `-t <timefmt>` option, but you're not adding those timestamps, thus the information is lost and `text2pcap` does the only thing it can do, which is to increment the timestamps for each packet so the packets at least remain in chronological order.  Refer to the `text2pcap` man page on the expected timestamp format and `-t` option.

Comment: Thank you for the timely reply, this ok but the time stamp should not change in the output file. so now we are trying to deal with the Byte value from pcap file.